# How to reverse engineer a database file format?

Tags: database, reverse, file-format

It is an accounting database whose database file format is proprietary data. But the problem is the database is highly unreliable, corruption go unnoticed for years after which it becomes unbearably difficult to recover data, we maintain accounts of lots of companies, so reversing the format will be highly useful. Also, the software is odbc compliant which might be very helpul for reversing it.The software is partially open-source, i.e. except database engine everything is open-source(and fully customizable), though they have there own different language.
I have no experience in reversing. we would like to reverse it in such a way that we could write data in that format directly. So I would like to know where I could get tools and how should I approach this, any articles or videos will be awesome.

Comment: Which DBMS database is it?

Comment: In the manual it states it is hierarchial but when using it with odbc I find it to be relational.

Comment: Is it Oracle DB, SQL Server DB or MySQL or what..?

Comment: It is a proprietary database format.

Comment: It is very difficult to rev-engineer the databases of very commonly used DBMSes. While it may be easier to rev-engineer this particular company's db, you can never really be sure that you did it right. You are better off therefore to export the data to .txt files and zip and store them.

Comment: Just to clarify - rev-engineering a db is not a science for which you can find tools or tutorials. Only hit-and-trial is the possible approach and therefore better that it be avoided completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's not so "hard". For example, I like hybrid solution:

1. Basic target file analyze: entropy, signatures, etc. It will be a good idea to look at possible chunks with some hex-editor (be ready to live in hex-editor for a long time), I recommend you 010 Editor with templates / scripts inside. Basic target application analyze: you need to understand how it was written (language, frameworks, libraries and so on) it'll be really useful on next steps.
2. Classic rev-engineering of application that can open this file format. Best way to use something like IDA Pro + Hex-Rays (but be ready to spend a lot of money) to generate C-like sources. You can break target file (change / steal some bytes) and break on exception in target application, for example, to start exploration.
3. Try to use FileMon (now it's a part of ProcMon) to understand how target applications reads target file. Sometimes it's possible (some applications doesn't use read buffer at all, so, you will see small readings + call stack for exploration!).
4. Different tools that can help you in some cases.

Best of all, upload few samples of database and application and give a link. We can try to do it together and write a little tutorial for others.